# Не работает kivy designer

Tags: python, kivy

Пишу:

```
(base) Mac-mini:~ admin$ kivy -m designer
-bash: kivy: command not found
```

Comment: не знаю ничего про киви, но судя по всему в виртуальном окружении не установлен этот пакет. Введите команду pip freeze, есть ли там киви?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934433/bash-kivy-command-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A!Надо было так:

```
cd kivy-designer
python -m designer
```